# Replace words that start from underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a block of text and each word in it, that starts from underscore should be replaced with another unique string.

For example:

```
_word -> _a 
_anotherword -> _b
_another_word -> _c
._dotwithword -> ._d
[_brword] -> [_e]
another_word -> another_word (should stay the same)
```

I'm using this regex to find them - (_\w+) , and it replaces everything correctly, except the last one if underscore is in the middle of the word. Is there any way to check this via JS regex?

JS fiddle to test: http://jsfiddle.net/C93bs/3/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(\b_\w+)` - `\b` matches on a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: even better than the answer I was about to post. I momentarily forgot about \b!

Answer (score 3):

Complete regexp (works in your fiddle):

```
/\b(_\w+)\b/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the nicest solution but it should work:

`/((^|\s)[\,\[\.]?_\w+(\])?)/g`

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFxqy/)

**EDIT: Beyamor solution is much cleaner**